# curl command example with service provider certificate

Tags: java, ssl, curl, jax-ws, ws-security

I have a question on usage of curl command. So basically we are trying to consume couple of  third party services have which supports ssl. We have two different vendor's

1. One vendor has configured their service with ssl which needs a client authentication. For which we had two keys one is private key with public key of ours .we gave our public key to them and we got their public key with certificate.we had a unix client with curl for that we generated the .pem file with the following command "cat server.crt serverpublickey.key > server.pem" and used curl command to call thier service.It worked fine.In this vendor case we never used to get the wsdl from browser. It used to show it needs a client authentication.
2. We have another vendor which services are configured with ssl but they did not configure with client authentication.So we were able to hit the wsdl link the browser which used to asked us to accept their certificate and we accepted the certificate in the browser and we were able to see the wsdl file. Technically when we hit any site with https:// they send the public certificate and public key .so browser encrypts the data with the key and send back to the server and when we get the data from the server the browser decryption happens with the public key. Now the question is how to call this services from curl ? I guess the previous vendor for every request we send our public key so that they will know it is coming from our side. In the other vendor case they have an authentication service .once we authenticated successfully they are sending us a session id which we need to use for the respective calls. This is the reason why i guess they never had a client authentication configuration with their ssl. Again this is my guess...

"Now my question is for the second vendor we have only the certificate which we got it in the browser. Can some one tell how to call the curl command with the certificate and make call to the third party service "

I might be wrong in some concepts.Any answers to my understanding is also appreciable

Comment: I believe this question is more appropriate for http://superuser.com//

Comment: just do it as in first case. `curl --cacert path_to_crt ... other  params`

Comment: How to accept the answer....i dont see any thing which says accept or any flag in the answer which is provided here..

Comment: I just clicked on voted tge answer..?is that what is considered as an acceptance..?

Comment: curl --cacert path_to_crt ... other params ...i have only their certificate...not ours...I mean when i hit the wsdl we got the certificate from the browser..i guess we can not use our certificate which we used to consume the first vendors service call...This is a different vendor ...

Comment: For this vendor all i have is their certificate thats all..